# Query result header after left join select

Tags: mysql, header, left-join

I'm having some difficulties building some multidimensional queries.

My problem is that, for example this query:

```
SELECT 
    persons.name, 
    contacts.email 
FROM 
    persons
LEFT JOIN 
    contacts ON persons.person_ID = contacts.person_ID
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Returns 2 columns as it should, 1 column with the name: 'name' and the other column with the name 'email'.

But the way I want it to return me the headers is like this:

```
'persons.name'
```

and

```
'contacts.email'
```

(I do not want to create a view, nor use aliases, or subqueries)

Is it even possible ? IF yes how ?

Thank you in advance for you help.

To give more details:

I am storing the query db, main table, and columns in a table. The columns are then built into an array, and based on that array I build up a query

There are cases when the columns are subqueries, sometimes they are only a table cells, and sometimes they are values of 2 or more columns

My problem is that after building the query dynamically, I have to display it, but if the array that contains the header names is defined as table.colname,

```
print $row[$array[column_name]]
```

evaluates to `print $row[persons.name]`

But the index that mysql server is generating, is 'name' and not 'persons.name'

that should work also, but if the query has 2 names, in it, that is ambiguous, and I do not see the option to pass a where condition after the query has been run.

That is the reason I do not want to use aliases in the first place

Comment: Why don't you want to use aliases?

Comment: Aliases would be the correct solution.

Comment: if you dont want to use aliases then give table columns these names without . instead use camel casing or underscore

Comment: I wonder why aliases are not an option? Please explain

Comment: basically my given examle is oversimlified, but it states my problem at the best, if there would be a way to force the select statement to return the indexes as tablename.colname, that would by great
I do not want to use aliases because you can not do a select where alias = something

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'AS' keyword to give an alias

```
SELECT persons.name as persons.name, contacts.email as contacts.email 
FROM presons 
LEFT JOIN contacts ON persons.person_ID=contatcs.person_ID 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as i specified it in my original post, i do not want to use aliases for given reasons

Comment: I don't what problem you have, but if you explain your original problem, there might be other solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

try using aliases

```
 SELECT persons.name AS 'person.name', contacts.email AS 'contacts.email' FROM presons
 LEFT JOIN contacts ON persons.person_ID=contatcs.person_ID
 LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as i specified it in my original post, i do not want to use aliases for some reasons